# Can't use proxy in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, proxy

I'm a bit noob to network stuff, i'm not using vite (what ever was that), i've just created a simple proxy server in order to proxy to my vue site, i've searched tons of pages and didn't get the solution and yes when u guys see the error it will look simple, trust me i've checked the old endpoint URL znd it matches the resulting URL of the proxy, they point to the same place

```
     this is the code to fetch the server:

async fetchtasks() {
      const res = await fetch("api/tasks");
      const data=res.json()
      return data;
    },

        code in vue.config.js:

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:5000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/api' },
                logLevel: 'debug',
                ws: true,
            },
        },
    }
};
```

when i use 'http://localhost:5000' it works well but after i replace it with api it returns the "unexpected token < in json error", i know it's an html page, how do i get rid of it? the code is right, and i've tried different tweaks... nothing worked

Comment: Check request details. It's not enough to know it's html page, you can see it with your eyes in dev tools. `fetch("api/tasks")` is not the same as `fetch("/api/tasks")`

Comment: @EstusFlask i've already tried that and tried it again this time to make sure, it didn't work, /api/tasks and api/tasks both don't work

Comment: What is running at `localhost:5000`? That server is likely returning `index.html` as a fallback, which means the requested URL (e.g., `/api/foo`) is not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
  module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL_API,
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```